# How to use multiple cursors in mysql.connector?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, mysql-connector-python

I want to execute multiple queries without each blocking other. I created multiple cursors and did the following but got `mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

```
import mysql.connector as mc
from threading import Thread

conn = mc.connect(#...username, password)
cur1 = conn.cursor()
cur2 = conn.cursor()

e1 = Thread(target=cur1.execute, args=("do sleep(30)",)) # A 'time taking' task
e2 = Thread(target=cur2.execute, args=("show databases",)) # A simple task

e1.start()
e2.start()
```

But I got that OperationalError. And reading a few other questions, some suggest that using multiple connections is better than multiple cursors. So shall I use multiple connections?

Comment: Try to create the cursors in the threads.

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use multiple connections? This might not be possible with cursors. It's not with MySQLdb anyway, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11927168/10682164).

Comment: @KlausD. will try that, thanks.

Comment: @totalhack I thought making multiple connections would be heavy compared to that of cursors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the full context of your situation to understand the performance considerations. Yes, starting a new connection could be considered heavy if you are operating under strict timing constraints that are short relative to the time it takes to start a new connection and you were forced to do that for every query...

But you can mitigate that with a shared connection [pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html) that you create ahead of time, and then distribute your queries (in separate threads) over those connections as resources allow.

On the other hand, if all of your query times are fairly long relative to the time it takes to create a new connection, and you aren't looking to run more than a handful of queries in parallel, then it can be a reasonable option to create connections on demand. Just be aware that you will run into limits with the number of open connections if you try to go too far, as well as resource limitations on the database system itself. You probably don't want to do something like that against a shared database. Again, this is only a reasonable option within some very specific contexts.

Comment: Accepted for introducing the idea of `pool`. Upvoted too ^^

Comment: Clearly the SO community doesn't like your question. Or my answer. Ironically their feedback, or lack thereof, is worse. My only guess is they thought you probably could have found other answers on your own through more research. I don't necessarily disagree with that, but thought it best to be helpful.

Comment: Okay... I wish it could be better if they provided comments for downvotes